# Casting a String Into a Function in R

Tags: r, function, casting

I have a Shiny app in R where I want users to be able to create functions on the fly by entering text in a text box.  To enable this functionality, I would like to know the following:

How would I go about casting a string object containing a function definition into an *actual* function, binding it to a variable name?

For example:

```
function_code = 'function(x) { as.dist(1-cor(t(x))) }'
f = something(function_code, ...)
```

Where `something()` converts `function_code` into an actual function and assigns it to variable `f`.  I don't think I can cast `function_code` into a function directly, and I've tried using `as.function` and that didn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `parse()` and `eval()`:

```
foo <- eval(parse(text = function_code))

> foo
function(x) { as.dist(1-cor(t(x))) }
```

Just wrap that in a function:

```
parseEval <- function(text) {
  eval(parse(text = text))
}
```

If you need an actual `something()` rather than a direct call.

Here's an example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(runif(20), ncol = 2)
out <- foo(x)
```

Giving

```
> zapsmall(out)
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2  0                
3  2 2              
4  0 0 2            
5  2 2 0 2          
6  0 0 2 0 2        
7  0 0 2 0 2 0      
8  2 2 0 2 0 2 2    
9  0 0 2 0 2 0 0 2  
10 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 0 2
```

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I had tried eval(parse(function_code)), but was missing the "text = " part, for any other noobs out there :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
input <- list()
input$f <- "x^2 + 2"
f <- function(x) eval(parse(text = input$f)) # text to function
f(2)
# [1] 6
```

This way your user doesn't need to write the `function(x)` part.  When you do this kind of thing though, your program is vulnerable in case a user adds in system calls (`system`).

Answer (score 2):

That's basically the function of the `source` function.

```
f <- source(textConnection(function_code))$value
#--------
> f
function(x) { as.dist(1-cor(t(x))) }
```

Comment: It has the advantage that it is well tested code (that can be examined as a best=practices guide) and with many options for special cases and situations that you may not have considered yet.